# Raw query not populating one-to-many association

Tags: sqlite, go-gorm

I have the following `sqlite` query:

```
SELECT
    orders.id
    , orders.shop_id
    , tv.total_value
    , line_items.id
    , line_items.product_id
    , line_items.order_id
    , line_items.description
    , line_items.quantity
    , products.price AS 'line_items.price'
FROM orders
JOIN line_items ON line_items.order_id = orders.id
JOIN products ON line_items.product_id = products.id
JOIN (
        SELECT
                line_items.order_id
            , SUM(products.price * line_items.quantity) total_value
        FROM line_items
        LEFT JOIN products ON line_items.product_id = products.id
        GROUP BY
                line_items.order_id
        ) tv ON tv.order_id = orders.id
```

which returns the following dataset:

[image: SQL query dataset]

with the following models:

```
type Order struct {
    ID         int64      `json:"id"`
    ShopID     int64      `json:"shopID"`
    TotalValue float64    `json:"total"`
    LineItems  []LineItem `json:"lineItems"`
}

type LineItem struct {
    ID          int64   `json:"id"`
    ProductID   *int64  `json:"productID"`
    OrderID     *int64  `json:"orderID"`
    Description string  `json:"description"`
    Quantity    int64   `json:"quantity"`
    Price       float64 `json:"price"`
}
```

---

**Question**: I want to execute Gorm's `Raw()` function to populate a `models.Order` object like so:

```
var orders models.Order
db.Raw(query).Scan(&orders)
```

This `Raw()` call correctly populates the `Order.ID`, `Order.ShopID`, and `Order.TotalValue` as expected. However, it doesn't populate any `LineItem` information although the provided query returns the necessary data.

The documentation for [`Raw()`](http://gorm.io/docs/sql_builder.html#Run-Raw-SQL) says it can't be chained with `Preload()`.

Is this achievable?